# Need to have http added if not present before www

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

My function gets all the facebook description text from our string $FBdescription. This preg_replace does everything I need except when it finds a url like www.myurl.com in the description it places that in the href= and because it does not contain the http:// at the begining it of course causes problems when you click the link. How can this be adjusted to append the http:// if it's not there.

```
function fts_facebook_tag_filter($FBdescription)
    //Converts URLs to Links in our Description Text
    $FBdescription = preg_replace('@(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-‌​Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $FBdescription);
    return $FBdescription;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not best but working solution: (prepends `http://` if missing, inside href attribute only)

```
$FBdescription = 'BZRK Records and BZRK Black label Artists playing here More info : www.bzrk.agency https://www.facebook.com/daphne.merks/posts/988562257858538';

//Converts URLs to Links
$FBdescription = preg_replace('@(?!(?!.*?<a)[^<]*<\/a>)(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-‌​Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank">\0</a>', $FBdescription);


$splitano = explode("www", $FBdescription);
$count = count($splitano);
$returnValue = "";

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    if (substr($splitano[$i], -6, 5) == "href=") {
        $returnValue .= $splitano[$i] . "http://www";
    }
    else if($i < $count - 1){
        $returnValue .= $splitano[$i] . "www";
    }
    else {
        $returnValue .= $splitano[$i];
    }
}
echo $returnValue;
```

Comment: s.o.b, and I spent hours on that before posting here! lol BIG Thanks!

Comment: Shoot actually I made a mistake I had my jquery still in place that was converting it, After removing that and just having the new code above it's not working as expected.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It's not actually converting instances of www

Comment: Maybe I should add that $FBdescription does not return just a url but a whole bunch of words.

Comment: ah, it returns <a> tag.. In that case we can use strpos.

Comment: I created an example where the code can be run to check if your edits work, I tried that latest edit with no luck. Thanks for helping! http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/038aaa3d66b6dae3be4e1636047f62d77166b834

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ceb0d9f2f0d227a23f048a7af744bd7649806b4

Comment: That worked! Thank-You. can you fix it so it only appends the http:// to the href="" portion?

Comment: I fixed it to append inside href only.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39a3e8a58ad23cc749e617f7e0ddce462932eda3